# Remove white space under overflow-auto div

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, overflow

I have added the css property "overflow: auto;" to bootstrap tabs.
It works, but there is a white space below the tabs.

Any ideas what am I doing wrong ? Thanks

I've tried to change the height, switch to overflow hidden, but no success there.

Working example:
https://codepen.io/carlo-designer/full/WBrxra
https://codepen.io/carlo-designer/pen/WBrxra

Expected result:
No white space at the bottom of the page

Code below ( please use bootstrap 4.3 )

```css
.h-40 {height:40%;}  
.h-10 {height:10%;}
.h-50 {height:50%;}
.over {overflow:auto;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha256-YLGeXaapI0/5IgZopewRJcFXomhRMlYYjugPLSyNjTY=" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha256-fzFFyH01cBVPYzl16KT40wqjhgPtq6FFUB6ckN2+GGw=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<div class="h-25 container text-center py-5"><h1>See below</h2></div>


<div class="container my-4">


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="list-group over h-50" id="list-tab" role="tablist">
        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="list-home-list" data-toggle="tab" href="#list-home" role="tab" aria-controls="list-home" aria-selected="false">Home</a>
        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="list-profile-list" data-toggle="tab" href="#list-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="list-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="list-messages-list" data-toggle="tab" href="#list-messages" role="tab" aria-controls="list-messages" aria-selected="false">Messages</a>
        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active" id="list-settings-list" data-toggle="tab" href="#list-settings" role="tab" aria-controls="list-settings" aria-selected="true">Settings</a>
        
         <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="list-profile-list" data-toggle="tab" href="#list-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="list-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="list-messages-list" data-toggle="tab" href="#list-messages" role="tab" aria-controls="list-messages" aria-selected="false">Messages</a>
        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active" id="list-settings-list" data-toggle="tab" href="#list-settings" role="tab" aria-controls="list-settings" aria-selected="true">Settings</a>
        
        
                <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="list-profile-list" data-toggle="tab" href="#list-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="list-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="list-messages-list" data-toggle="tab" href="#list-messages" role="tab" aria-controls="list-messages" aria-selected="false">Messages</a>
        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active" id="list-settings-list" data-toggle="tab" href="#list-settings" role="tab" aria-controls="list-settings" aria-selected="true">Settings</a>
        
                <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="list-profile-list" data-toggle="tab" href="#list-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="list-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="list-messages-list" data-toggle="tab" href="#list-messages" role="tab" aria-controls="list-messages" aria-selected="false">Messages</a>
        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active" id="list-settings-list" data-toggle="tab" href="#list-settings" role="tab" aria-controls="list-settings" aria-selected="true">Settings</a>
        
        
                        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="list-profile-list" data-toggle="tab" href="#list-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="list-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="list-messages-list" data-toggle="tab" href="#list-messages" role="tab" aria-controls="list-messages" aria-selected="false">Messages</a>
        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active" id="list-settings-list" data-toggle="tab" href="#list-settings" role="tab" aria-controls="list-settings" aria-selected="true">Settings</a>
        
        
        
                        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="list-profile-list" data-toggle="tab" href="#list-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="list-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="list-messages-list" data-toggle="tab" href="#list-messages" role="tab" aria-controls="list-messages" aria-selected="false">Messages</a>
        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active" id="list-settings-list" data-toggle="tab" href="#list-settings" role="tab" aria-controls="list-settings" aria-selected="true">Settings</a>
        
        
        
                        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="list-profile-list" data-toggle="tab" href="#list-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="list-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="list-messages-list" data-toggle="tab" href="#list-messages" role="tab" aria-controls="list-messages" aria-selected="false">Messages</a>
        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active" id="list-settings-list" data-toggle="tab" href="#list-settings" role="tab" aria-controls="list-settings" aria-selected="true">Settings</a>
        
        
        
                        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="list-profile-list" data-toggle="tab" href="#list-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="list-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="list-messages-list" data-toggle="tab" href="#list-messages" role="tab" aria-controls="list-messages" aria-selected="false">Messages</a>
        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active" id="list-settings-list" data-toggle="tab" href="#list-settings" role="tab" aria-controls="list-settings" aria-selected="true">Settings</a>
        
        
                        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="list-profile-list" data-toggle="tab" href="#list-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="list-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="list-messages-list" data-toggle="tab" href="#list-messages" role="tab" aria-controls="list-messages" aria-selected="false">Messages</a>
        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active" id="list-settings-list" data-toggle="tab" href="#list-settings" role="tab" aria-controls="list-settings" aria-selected="true">Settings</a>
        
        
                        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="list-profile-list" data-toggle="tab" href="#list-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="list-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="list-messages-list" data-toggle="tab" href="#list-messages" role="tab" aria-controls="list-messages" aria-selected="false">Messages</a>
        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active" id="list-settings-list" data-toggle="tab" href="#list-settings" role="tab" aria-controls="list-settings" aria-selected="true">Settings</a>
        
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-8">
      <div class="tab-content over  h-40" id="nav-tabContent">
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="list-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="list-home-list">
          <p>Velit aute mollit ipsum ad dolor consectetur nulla officia culpa adipisicing exercitation fugiat tempor. Voluptate deserunt sit sunt nisi aliqua fugiat proident ea ut. Mollit voluptate reprehenderit occaecat nisi ad non minim tempor sunt voluptate consectetur exercitation id ut nulla. Ea et fugiat aliquip nostrud sunt incididunt consectetur culpa aliquip eiusmod dolor. Anim ad Lorem aliqua in cupidatat nisi enim eu nostrud do aliquip veniam minim.</p>


          <p>Velit aute mollit ipsum ad dolor consectetur nulla officia culpa adipisicing exercitation fugiat tempor. Voluptate deserunt sit sunt nisi aliqua fugiat proident ea ut. Mollit voluptate reprehenderit occaecat nisi ad non minim tempor sunt voluptate consectetur exercitation id ut nulla. Ea et fugiat aliquip nostrud sunt incididunt consectetur culpa aliquip eiusmod dolor. Anim ad Lorem aliqua in cupidatat nisi enim eu nostrud do aliquip veniam minim.</p>
          
          
          
          <p>Velit aute mollit ipsum ad dolor consectetur nulla officia culpa adipisicing exercitation fugiat tempor. Voluptate deserunt sit sunt nisi aliqua fugiat proident ea ut. Mollit voluptate reprehenderit occaecat nisi ad non minim tempor sunt voluptate consectetur exercitation id ut nulla. Ea et fugiat aliquip nostrud sunt incididunt consectetur culpa aliquip eiusmod dolor. Anim ad Lorem aliqua in cupidatat nisi enim eu nostrud do aliquip veniam minim.</p>
          
          
          <p>Velit aute mollit ipsum ad dolor consectetur nulla officia culpa adipisicing exercitation fugiat tempor. Voluptate deserunt sit sunt nisi aliqua fugiat proident ea ut. Mollit voluptate reprehenderit occaecat nisi ad non minim tempor sunt voluptate consectetur exercitation id ut nulla. Ea et fugiat aliquip nostrud sunt incididunt consectetur culpa aliquip eiusmod dolor. Anim ad Lorem aliqua in cupidatat nisi enim eu nostrud do aliquip veniam minim.</p>          
                              
          
          
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="list-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="list-profile-list">
          <p>Cupidatat quis ad sint excepteur laborum in esse qui. Et excepteur consectetur ex nisi eu do cillum ad laborum. Mollit et eu officia dolore sunt Lorem culpa qui commodo velit ex amet id ex. Officia anim incididunt laboris deserunt anim aute dolor incididunt veniam aute dolore do exercitation. Dolor nisi culpa ex ad irure in elit eu dolore. Ad laboris ipsum reprehenderit irure non commodo enim culpa commodo veniam incididunt veniam ad.</p>
          

          <p>Velit aute mollit ipsum ad dolor consectetur nulla officia culpa adipisicing exercitation fugiat tempor. Voluptate deserunt sit sunt nisi aliqua fugiat proident ea ut. Mollit voluptate reprehenderit occaecat nisi ad non minim tempor sunt voluptate consectetur exercitation id ut nulla. Ea et fugiat aliquip nostrud sunt incididunt consectetur culpa aliquip eiusmod dolor. Anim ad Lorem aliqua in cupidatat nisi enim eu nostrud do aliquip veniam minim.</p>
          
          
                    <p>Velit aute mollit ipsum ad dolor consectetur nulla officia culpa adipisicing exercitation fugiat tempor. Voluptate deserunt sit sunt nisi aliqua fugiat proident ea ut. Mollit voluptate reprehenderit occaecat nisi ad non minim tempor sunt voluptate consectetur exercitation id ut nulla. Ea et fugiat aliquip nostrud sunt incididunt consectetur culpa aliquip eiusmod dolor. Anim ad Lorem aliqua in cupidatat nisi enim eu nostrud do aliquip veniam minim.</p>
                    
                    
                              <p>Velit aute mollit ipsum ad dolor consectetur nulla officia culpa adipisicing exercitation fugiat tempor. Voluptate deserunt sit sunt nisi aliqua fugiat proident ea ut. Mollit voluptate reprehenderit occaecat nisi ad non minim tempor sunt voluptate consectetur exercitation id ut nulla. Ea et fugiat aliquip nostrud sunt incididunt consectetur culpa aliquip eiusmod dolor. Anim ad Lorem aliqua in cupidatat nisi enim eu nostrud do aliquip veniam minim.</p>
                              
                              
                                        <p>Velit aute mollit ipsum ad dolor consectetur nulla officia culpa adipisicing exercitation fugiat tempor. Voluptate deserunt sit sunt nisi aliqua fugiat proident ea ut. Mollit voluptate reprehenderit occaecat nisi ad non minim tempor sunt voluptate consectetur exercitation id ut nulla. Ea et fugiat aliquip nostrud sunt incididunt consectetur culpa aliquip eiusmod dolor. Anim ad Lorem aliqua in cupidatat nisi enim eu nostrud do aliquip veniam minim.</p>          
          
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="list-messages" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="list-messages-list">
          <p>Ut ut do pariatur aliquip aliqua aliquip exercitation do nostrud commodo reprehenderit aute ipsum voluptate. Irure Lorem et laboris nostrud amet cupidatat cupidatat anim do ut velit mollit consequat enim tempor. Consectetur est minim nostrud nostrud consectetur irure labore voluptate irure. Ipsum id Lorem sit sint voluptate est pariatur eu ad cupidatat et deserunt culpa sit eiusmod deserunt. Consectetur et fugiat anim do eiusmod aliquip nulla laborum elit adipisicing pariatur cillum.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade active show" id="list-settings" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="list-settings-list">
          <p>Irure enim occaecat labore sit qui aliquip reprehenderit amet velit. Deserunt ullamco ex elit nostrud ut dolore nisi officia magna sit occaecat laboris sunt dolor. Nisi eu minim cillum occaecat aute est cupidatat aliqua labore aute occaecat ea aliquip sunt amet. Aute mollit dolor ut exercitation irure commodo non amet consectetur quis amet culpa. Quis ullamco nisi amet qui aute irure eu. Magna labore dolor quis ex labore id nostrud deserunt dolor eiusmod eu pariatur culpa mollit in irure.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  
  
  
  
</div>
```

Comment: To verify, are you after removing the whitespace under the box (`.over`) where the content swaps out?

Comment: Actually, when you scroll down the entire page, there is a white space below the tabs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this

```
.row div[class*="col-"]{
  height: 100%;
}
```

and add `max-height:50vh;` instead of height 50%;

Comment: Correction It did work thanks! Replacing height with max-height fixed the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In flex box By default align-items: stretch;
You just need to add align-items: flex-start;

Comment: Hi. Can you be more precise ? Thanks

Comment: U have to fix the height in px its start working with scrolling